# How to cover holes in the wood floor?

Tags: flooring

I bought some new furniture recently including a heavy dining table and some couches which had steel framework along with wood. The problem is that when I was carrying the old table and items out I didn't notice the floor being damaged with scratches and some holes. The table has been in the same position for years now. There are some color changes to it along with small holes. The new furniture matches the antique hardwood flooring but the stuck dirt and holes which have some white powder are clearly visible by a person entering the room from out. Unless replacing the new furniture in the place of the old which will cover the hole, but the problem may get worsened, I can't find a solution. Should I do a refinish to the floor? or do some wood putty work to cover up the holes?

Comment: A photo would be helpful, the scratches and white power suggest a polyurethane and that may be able to be buffed and refinished.

Comment: it is unclear how the new furniture relates to the damaged floor .... why is it a problem that you did not notice the damage when you removed the old furniture? .... what would you have done differently if you did notice the damage before you removed the old furniture? ..... it seems that your story about the furniture clutters up your question with irrelevant facts ..... i think that your question boils down to just `I have damage on my floor. This is  what it looks like.  How can I repair it?` ... simple and to the point